# Pandas: Pad data-frame to max row length

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data-frame like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300], "val1": [1.5, 2.5, 4.5, np.nan, 6.5, np.nan], "val2": [9.5, 7.5, 8.5, 3.5, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

What I want to achieve is to zero pad each group (assuming that the data-frame is grouped by `id`), to the max number of rows for all groups. The max number of rows per `id` for the data-frame above is 3, so the resulting data-frame should look like the following:

```
df_true = pd.DataFrame({"id": [100, 100, 100, 200, 200 ,200, 300, 300, 300], "val1": [1.5, 0, 0, 2.5, 4.5, 0, np.nan, 6.5, np.nan], "val2": [9.5, 0, 0, 7.5, 8.5, 0, 3.5, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Can someone point me in the right direction how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we do with `cumcount` with id  then using `stack` and `unstack`

```
df['new']=df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df_true=df.set_index(['id','new']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack(dropna=False).reset_index('id')
df_true
Out[908]: 
      id  val1  val2
new                 
0    100   1.5   9.5
1    100   0.0   0.0
2    100   0.0   0.0
0    200   2.5   7.5
1    200   4.5   8.5
2    200   0.0   0.0
0    300   NaN   3.5
1    300   6.5   NaN
2    300   NaN   NaN
```